# Why people use bower and npm to inject any library into project

Tags: npm, bower

suppose i am working with asp.net mvc with VS2013 IDE. we can download **angular-ui-router js** file from any web site and copy that file in script folder of my project and refer those js file in web pages.

so my question is why i should use bower or npm to download js files like below example. please tell me extra advantage of using bower or npm to download js files ?

**bower install**

```
$ bower install angular-ui-router
```

npm install

```
$ npm install angular-ui-router
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the library evolves/updates or if the project is moved, those package managers allows to keep up to date with all the needed plugins, without having to look for each one, download the last/needed version of each one, and moving them where you need.

You don't need to use them if you don't need them. As any tool, they are there if you need them.